# should react services have static methods

Tags: reactjs

Should a react class that makes api call (a service) use static methods?

Eg:

```
class ProductService{
    static getAllProducts(){ return fetch(...)}    
    static saveProduct(){ return fetch(...)}
    ...   
}
```

Or should I create an instance eg. `(new ProductService()).getAllProducts`

Or Should I use a singleton pattern

I would rather use static methods because they are simpler and potentially faster. Also, it does not make sense to instantiate a class if there is no state specific to the instance.

Comment: Is that Java code?

Comment: It's typescript code

Comment: I removed the public modifier - so it's no longer typescript code. It's just JavaScript now

Comment: @Héctor Java code should have the return type on the method

Answer (score -1):

Short answer:
Just put your functions for one service in a file `my-service.js` or `my-service.ts` and use:

> `import {myFunction} from "../services/my-service.js`.

Long answer :
Static functions are not a good solution because they will be hard to mock if testing.

Without static, classes with only methods, like you are trying to do, raise ESLint error: `class-methods-use-this` on most methods for a service without state. The solution would be a singleton pattern for your classes. But it would be more work.

Just don't use a class.

So 2 solutions. First if your functions dosen't need states. Just add your functions in a JS file and import them.

In real use cases, most of them will need to update the state. So you will need to create custom hooks and contexts.

That's how services are done in React.
For example, to create a service with all your API calls to modify the list "products". You put the list in a context. And functions like fetchProduct in the hook. You will then have useProduct.js and ProductContect.js.
This allows to organize your code in multiple services.